# Triggers not working on Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I am getting an issue with execution of triggers. I am providing below the code for 1 of the triggers.

```
create or replace
TRIGGER abc_tr01
  BEFORE INSERT
  ON tablename
  FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
  UPDATE tablename
     SET dtCreatedDate = SYSDATE
     WHERE incidentid = ( SELECT :NEW.incidentid 
                            FROM DUAL  );
END;
```

This trigger is supposed to update 1 of the columns ( `dtCreatedDate` ) of the `tablename` table and stores `SYSDATE` in it before an insertion is carried out on that table.

It is failing to update the `dtCreatedDate` field however.

I have checked that the trigger is enabled. It is getting fired at the insertion time too. I checked that by injecting a syntax error in the trigger code which was promptly detected.

I am using SQL Developer 3.0.

Please help.

Comment: There is no need to issue an `update` statement in the trigger body if `tablename` in the `on` clause of the trigger and `tablename` in the `update` statement are the same. Just use `:new` qualifier of the column you want to assign a value to. `:new.dtCreatedDate := SYSDATE`

Comment: When it got fired you most certainly got a "*table is mutating" error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for the `UPDATE` statement:

```
create or replace
TRIGGER abc_tr01
  BEFORE INSERT
  ON tablename
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  :new.dtCreatedDate := sysdate;
END;
/
```